# GeoJSON file content not display properly in Leaflet

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, geojson, coordinates, proj4leaflet

I am new to Leaflet. Am facing one issue when try to display GeoJSON file in Leaflet.

Issue:

Actually some GeoJSON file only am facing this problem.  In my knowledge coordinates are in different format so that am facing this issue.

Please find below sample feature code: coordinates are in high values like `[ 352.90679825050762, 891.44899536185403 ]` so that it is not projecting properly.  So can anyone explain how to convert/change the coordinates (working coordinates for Leaflet) like `[ -2.978663816550748, 56.459992535783947 ]`?

```
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Layer": "ANNO-HATCH-ELEV", "SubClasses": "AcDbEntity:AcDbHatch", "ExtendedEntity": "     5      2", "Linetype": "ByBlock", "EntityHandle": "A3475", "Text": "ANSI32" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 352.90679825050762, 891.44899536185403 ], [ 352.90679825050762, 895.32399536185403 ], [ 343.90679825050762, 895.32399536185403 ], [ 343.90679825050762, 883.2927453618795 ], [ 352.90679825049301, 883.2927453618795 ], [ 352.90679825050762, 891.44899536185403 ] ] ] } }
```

Comment: Your GeoJSON does not conform to the specification. Read https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7946#section-4

Comment: This is mysteriously similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62275657/leaflet-how-to-display-a-geojson-file-with-autocad-data from yesterday, so I'm forced to guess this is some kind of school assignment.

Comment: Okay IvanSanchez.But that same geojson working fine in Openlayer....

Comment: What actual CRS is meant to be represented in your GeoJSON file?

Comment: The `AcDbEntity:AcDbHatch` property leads me to think that it's AutoCAD data, and not GIS data.

Comment: If this GeoJSON works OK in OpenLayers, please add relevant part of the OpenLayers code to your question.

Comment: Openlayer code:                                                                                                         
        const features = (new GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geojson);
          features.forEach(feature => {
            const geometryValue: Geometry = feature.getGeometry();
            geometryValue.translate(x, y);
          });                                                                                                                                                                          where X and Y  geojson position coordinates..

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got a solution by unprojecting CRS EPSG3857 then the same geojson file working fine in leaflet.

By adding,

```
L.CRS.EPSG3857.unproject(point) // where point is coords.
```